# How to scroll through Ubuntu server (keyboard)?

Tags: command-line, server, scrolling, vmware-fusion

How can you scroll through previous output on the terminal screen (keyboard)? shift+pgup does not work, shift+pgdown produces "~", shift+up shows history and shift+down does nothing.

I do not want to scroll up in a text editor, just
ALL terminal output.

Running Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS, Linux 5.4.0-65-generic on VMware Fusion (Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7)

Answer (score 0):

I have actual machine I connect to it through the `Terminal.app` in `Catalina` via the `ssh` program. This allows you to view all the output by scrolling back in the terminal view displayed with your mouse. You may want to give it a try, doing it inside `VMWare` no clue.